# [Android ADB]"adb shell logcat" write to internal memory failed to execute intermittently

Tags: android, shell, adb, logcat

I tried to capture logcat & store into the device's internal memory. But notice that, this doesn't work intermittently. Doesn't work in the scene that, 0 bytes logcat was generated.

Command that I used, and failed intermittently.

```
adb shell "logcat -b main -v threadtime > /data/logcat.log &"
```

BUT if I stored it directly to my PC, it works perfectly.

```
adb shell logcat -b main -v threadtime > logcat.log &
```

ADB version : Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a commercial, non-rooted device, `/data/` is not writeable.  The shell runs as the `shell` user.  That part of the flash is only writeable by `root` or `system` users.  If you really want to write to the device for some reason, write to `/data/local/tmp` instead.

Comment: Hi Larry, forgot to mention, device is under user debug mode (root), & issue happened intermittently.

Comment: Tough to say what it could be without more details or debugging.  But, in general, you probably don't want to write logcat output to the `/data/` volume.

Comment: The reason why I tried to store into /data/ instead of PC is I am troubleshooting some issues where USB port is not available.
And the procedures are:
1. Plug in USB
2. adb shell "logcat -b main -v threadtime > /data/logcat.log &"
3. Unplug USB.
4. <Reproduce Issue e.g. USB Tethering>
5. Plug in USB
6. Dump out logcat.log